# Can't get this code to work: A bisector search that finds the best saving rate in order to pay the down payment of a house

Tags: python

Right now, I'm trying to solve a lab question from MIT 6.00I

You are now going to try to find the best rate of savings to achieve a down payment on a $1M house in 36 months. Since hitting this exactly is a challenge, we simply want your savings to be within $100 of the required down payment.

Write a program to calculate the best savings rate, as a function of your starting salary. You should use ​bisection search(https://www.rookieslab.com/posts/linear-search-vs-bisection-search-in-python)​ to help you do this efficiently. You should keep track of the number of steps it takes your bisections search to finish. You should be able to reuse some of the code you wrote for part B in this problem.

Because we are searching for a value that is in principle a float, we are going to limit ourselves to two decimals of accuracy (i.e., we may want to save at 7.04% ­­ or 0.0704 in decimal – but we are not going to worry about the difference between 7.041% and 7.039%). This means we can search for an integer​ between 0 and 10000 (using integer division), and then convert it to a decimal percentage (using float division) to use when we are calculating the ​current_savings​ after 36 months. By using this range, there are only a finite number of numbers that we are searching over, as opposed to the infinite number of decimals between 0 and 1. This range will help prevent infinite loops. The reason we use 0 to 10000 is to account for two additional decimal places in the range 0% to 100%. Your code should print out a decimal (e.g. 0.0704 for 7.04%).

This is my code:

```
while True:
  try:
    startingSalary = int(input('Enter the starting salary: '))
    break
  except ValueError:
    pass
  
semiRaise = 0.07
investmentReturn = 0.04
houseCost = 1000000
downPayment = houseCost * 0.25
high = 10000
low = 0
savingsRate = ((low + high) / 2) / 10000
savings = 0
steps = 0
months = 0
monthlySalary = startingSalary / 12

while downPayment - savings > 100 and months <= 36:
  savingsRate = ((low + high) / 2) / 10000
  savings += monthlySalary * savingsRate
  savings += savings * (investmentReturn / 12)
  months += 1
  if months % 6 == 0:
    monthlySalary += monthlySalary * semiRaise
    
  if savings < downPayment:
    low = savingsRate
  elif savings > downPayment:
    high = savingsRate
  steps += 1 
  
print('Best savings rate: ', savingsRate)
print('Steps in bisection search: ', steps)
```

This is my output:

```
Enter the starting salary:  150000
Best savings rate:  0.5000250012500626
Steps in bisection search:  33
```

But my output is completely wrong, the correct output is supposed to be:

```
Enter the starting salary:​ 150000 

Best savings rate:​ 0.4411
Steps in bisection search:​ 12
```

Can someone identify what I did wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: Why did you do this? ```rate = (low + high) // 2``` Shouldn't it just have one  ```/```?

Comment: It sounds like you need two nested loops. The outer one calculates different savings rates, but the inner one should use that savings rate over 36 months. You should try to write the inner loop as it’s own function so you can test it independently.

Comment: at first look over your calculation of rate.  
it implies you can save your monthly salary 5000 times within a month. I would like to know how to do that ;)

Comment: Why is your monthly salary the starting salary/12? Is the starting salary the amount you are told you will get for a year? Because I think it is more likely you are paid for the amount of time you work and not a set yearly salary. Essentially the real question: Is the starting salary the same as an annual salary?